# Inconsistent background video playback with Google Chrome browser

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, html5-video

I understand that Google's Autoplay Policy means background videos – e.g. as an opening splash on the home page – should still play automatically (on Chrome 66+) if they have no audio:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

However, I'm getting inconsistent results across two different Wordpress themes using the same background video which has no audio track.

I'm using Google Chrome v. 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) on a Windows 10 PC.

I've set up a test page using the Wordpress Twenty Seventeen theme and the background video plays fine for me: https://www.jmotion.co.uk/clients/Test_Site/

However the exact same video remains paused on the first frame on a test page on my company website which uses the THB Theme, Zancudo: https://www.jmotion.co.uk/t1/

I can only get this background video to play after opening Chrome's Inspector and doing a hard re-load: CTRL + Shift + R

The basic HTML coding appears to be broadly similar for each instance of the video, with neither including the “muted” attribute.

**TWENTY SEVENTEEN:**

video id="wp-custom-header-video" autoplay="" loop="" width="2000" height="1200" src="https://www.jmotion.co.uk/clients/Test_Site/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Cafe1280.mp4">

**ZANCUDO:**

video class="wp-video-shortcode thb-video-loaded" id="video-6193-1_html5" width="640" height="360" loop="1" autoplay="1" preload="metadata" src="https://www.jmotion.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Cafe1280.mp4?_=1" style="width: 1583px; height: 890.438px;">

I'm no coder (strictly copy/paste!), but I've dug around in both sets of theme files without success to try to work out why Chrome is handling these two instances of background video differently.

I've made sure that both themes are now feeding off the same version of “mediaelement”, but it's made no difference.

I've seen from other forum posts that adding “muted” into the video embed coding could be a solution. However, I can't find how to do this because the background video is placed automatically by each theme's programming into the header (not as HTML coding directly onto a page) – and I can't find how that *video* embed code is generated by either theme. Or is it generated by the Wordpress media.php and/or media-template.php files?

I'd really appreciate any help on this. I don't want to have to change themes – I really want to be able to use a background video on our Zancudo site if I can make it fully compatible with Chrome.

(By the way, I have no problems with playing the background video through Internet Explorer 11 and Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0 on Win10 PC, Safari 10 on iPad ios 10.3.3, Google Chrome 69 on iPad ios 10.3.3)

Thank you.

Comment: I get an error in the 2nd url `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.` A forced refresh and it loads and plays

Comment: Thanks RamRaider - this was helpful and fed into my research. In the end I've solved it by by adding a custom function into the theme's function.php file:

// Add Muted to all videos:

add_filter( 'wp_video_shortcode', function( $output ) {
$output = str_replace( '<video', '<video muted', $output );
return $output;
} );